# "(deleted)" is a bit misleading when something like a close vote has been accepted

Tags: feature-request, voting

Currently in the history for one's votes it says `(deleted)` if a vote has either been accepted, denied, or deleted.

So, for instance if I cast a close vote on a question and the question is closed, it will look like this:

[image]

Which is slightly confusing and may be misleading to some as they may think that the close vote was rejected in some way. It also does this for reopen votes, delete, and undelete votes, basically it does it for any vote if it's been accepted, rejected (in some way), or deleted (like if I cast a close vote, and then retract it).

So I think that the text displayed about the status of the vote should be more descriptive, so that it says `(deleted)`, `(denied)`, and `(accepted)`.